# How to remove bubble around Thumb in Android SeekBar?

Tags: java, android, seekbar, android-seekbar, seekbar-thumb

I have a little problem with my SeekBar. Does someone know, how I can remove the light blue bubble around Thumb in Android SeekBar?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add `android:background="@android:color/transparent"` to your `Seekbar`.

```
<SeekBar
    android:id="@+id/seekbar"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Comment: maybe do color/transparent instead, so that way even if you use it in a darker theme, it would still blend in with the background

Comment: @NikosHidalgo Thank you for the hint. I edited my answer.